# I want all page requests to point to a single page

Tags: iis-6, redirect

The wrinkle is that the pages being requested are aspx pages and they are no longer present. I want any request coming to the root domain (and any subdomain like www) to redirect to a single page in the root directory (namely index.html) I went into the IIS admin tool, selected the domain and tried to direct to a url (http://mydomain.com/index.html) but that caused index.html to be appended multiple times and resulted in an error.

What is the best way to do this, so that any http request ot hsi domain goes to the index.html page?

Thanks in advance.
Warren

Comment: In Apache you can set the page that gets displayed if the requested page was not found (a "404 error" page). There's probably a way to do that in IIS as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the ASP.Net App_Offline feature; if you place a file in the root of your website called App_Offline.htm, the contents of that file will be returned in response to all incoming requests.

Comment: Thank you Nick, this solved it. I am more of an Apache guy, so was a little bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

Or find your default 404.html file and put some redirection code into it